# Is it possible to define enumalpha?

Tags: c++, enums, iostream

I would like to be able to write:

```
cout << enumalpha << Monday;
```

and get printed on console:

Monday

P.S. Monday is an enum type.

Comment: No, not in the general case. It would have to know about all possible enumerations in order for it to work. You can of course write a function `ToString( enum Days );` which converts a Days enum value to a string.

Comment: @Neil Thanks I think I'll do that.

Comment: @Neil But those enums names must be stored somewhere so there should be a way to fork them out. Or not?

Comment: enum names are converted to numeric values by the compiler at compile time. They are no more accessible at run-time than are the names of variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, let's go all preprocessor then :)

Intended way of use:

```
DEFINE_ENUM(DayOfWeek, (Monday)(Tuesday)(Wednesday)
                       (Thursday)(Friday)(Saturday)(Sunday))

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  DayOfWeek_t i = DayOfWeek::Monday;
  std::cout << i << std::endl;            // prints Monday

  std::cin >> i >> std::endl;             // reads the content of a string and
                                          // deduce the corresponding enum value
}
```

Dark magic, involving the helpful [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/enum.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>

#define DEFINE_ENUM_VAL_TO_STR(r, data, elem)                      \
   case BOOST_PP_CAT(data, BOOST_PP_CAT(::, elem)):                \
    return out << BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem);

#define DEFINE_ENUM_STR_TO_VAL(r, data, elem)                      \
   if (s == BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem))                              \
   { i = BOOST_PP_CAT(data, BOOST_PP_CAT(::, elem)) ; } else


#define DEFINE_ENUM(Name, Values)                                  \
   struct Name {                                                   \
     enum type {                                                   \
       Invalid = 0,                                                \
       BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(Values)                                   \
     };                                                            \
   };                                                              \
   typedef Name::type Name##_t;                                    \
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Name##_t i) {       \
    switch(i) {                                                    \
      BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DEFINE_ENUM_VAL_TO_STR, Name, Values)  \
    default: return out << "~"; } }                                \
   std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Name##_t& i) {       \
     std::string s; in >> s;                                       \
     BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DEFINE_ENUM_STR_TO_VAL, Name, Values)   \
     { i = Name##::Invalid; } }
```

There are better ways, personally I use this little macro to store that all in a nicely sorted vector of pairs, static for the type, it also allows me to iterate through the values of the enum if the mood (or need) strikes :)

It's quite unfortunate though there is no support in the language for that. I would prefer if there was, enum are quite handy for codesets...

Answer (score 4):

The exact form of what you want is impossible, as far as I know. As Neil said, names are for us mere humans; the compiler deals with the values.

That said, you can make a utility for giving names to enums. Here's an example:

```
#define ENUM_NAMES_BEGIN(pType) \
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& pStream, pType pValue) \
            { \
                switch (pValue) \
                {

#define ENUM_NAMES_CASE_NAMED(pValue, pName) \
                case (pValue): \
                    pStream << (pName); \
                    break;

#define ENUM_NAMES_CASE(pValue) ENUM_NAMES_CASE_NAMED(pValue, #pValue)

#define ENUM_NAMES_END(pDefault) \
                default: \
                    pStream << (pDefault); \
                } \
                \
                return pStream; \
            }
```

You'd use it as such:

```
#include <iostream>

enum Days
{
    Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday
};

enum NotNamed
{
    DontTry, ImNotnamed
};

ENUM_NAMES_BEGIN(Days)
    ENUM_NAMES_CASE(Sunday)
    ENUM_NAMES_CASE(Monday)
    ENUM_NAMES_CASE(Tuesday)
    ENUM_NAMES_CASE(Wednesday)
    ENUM_NAMES_CASE(Thursday)
    ENUM_NAMES_CASE(Friday)
    ENUM_NAMES_CASE_NAMED(Saturday, "Saturday: Fun day!")
ENUM_NAMES_END("")

int main()
{
    Days d = Saturday; // or whatever
    NotNamed n = ImNotnamed;

    std::cout << "Day: " << d << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Not Named: " << n << std::endl;
}
```

Trying it with a type that is "unnamed" returns its numeric value.

Note, there isn't actually any enforcement of an enum here; you could use this to name integer values, for example. If you did, `operator<<` would be ambiguous.

If you can use Boost, use their type trait `is_enum` (which is fairly complex) and static assert that it be the case. For that the change would be:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_enum.hpp>

#define ENUM_NAMES_BEGIN(pType) \
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& pStream, pType pValue) \
            { \
                BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_enum<pType>::value); \
                switch (pValue) \
                {
```

Now if the type is not an enum, the compile-error at least point to the line where you're trying to define the enum names.

Comment: I thought of this, but then I decided it was too early on a Saturday morning^H^H^H^H^H^H^H afternoon to write macros.  ;-)  Very nice.  What happened to Sunday, though?  It's a fun day too!

Comment: Ouch, if you're going to use the preprocessor at least make it easy on the caller :p

Answer (score 2):

*(no, this doesn't answer the question for the general case, but it might still be of interest to somebody)*

As Neil says in the comments to this question, you can't do this in the general case for enumerations.  However, for individual cases, you can overload the stream insertion operator (`<<`) for an enumerated type:

```
#include <iostream>

enum day_of_week
{
    friday,
    saturday,
    sunday
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, day_of_week day)
{
    switch (day)
    {
    case friday:   o << "Friday";   break;
    case saturday: o << "Saturday"; break;
    case sunday:   o << "Sunday";   break;
    }
    return o;
}
```

For example, with the above code, this:

```
std::cout << saturday << std::endl;
```

will print:

```
Saturday
```

Comment: Damn, if I had waited one minute I'd of been able to be reminded I should be constructing the stream operator. :| I'm promptly stealing this. :) +1