# Overloading a macro

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I'm trying to overload a macro by the number of parameter.
Of course I can't actually overload the macro.

I've tried using variadic macros to choose the right macro (using the fact that if `__VA_ARGS__` doesn't exist it's supposed to delete the last coma before it - **[GCC Reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)**):

```
#define TEST1() printf("TEST1");
#define TEST2() printf("TEST2");

#define CHOOSER(x, y,FUNC,...) FUNC()

#define MANIMACRO(...) CHOOSER(,__VA_ARGS__,TEST1,TEST2)

int main(void)
{
    MANIMACRO(1);
    MANIMACRO();
}
```

The idea was that if `__VA_ARGS__` exists it should pass 4 arguments to **CHOOSER**, where the third one should have been "disappeared" with the unused args. so TEST1 would be chosen.

If there is no parameter the `__VA_ARGS__` would be null, and should have removed the coma, so **TEST2** would be chosen and used.

So, i guess that doesn't work because the `__VA_ARGS__` probably gets removed only at the end of the preprocessing stage, after the whole thing was already expanded.

So, how can I do such a thing? (in vs2010)

Comment: Is this link helpful? http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/03/default-arguments-for-c99/

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9338429/390913):

```
#define TEST1(expr)           printf("test1")
#define TEST2(expr, explain)  printf("test2")

#define N_ARGS_IMPL2(_1, _2, count, ...) \
   count
#define N_ARGS_IMPL(args) \
   N_ARGS_IMPL2 args
#define N_ARGS(...) N_ARGS_IMPL((__VA_ARGS__, 2, 1, 0))
 /* Pick the right helper macro to invoke. */
#define CHOOSER2(count) TEST##count
#define CHOOSER1(count) CHOOSER2(count)
#define CHOOSER(count)  CHOOSER1(count)
 /* The actual macro. */
#define TEST_GLUE(x, y) x y
#define TEST(...) \
   TEST_GLUE(CHOOSER(N_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)), \
               (__VA_ARGS__))

int main() {
  TEST(one); // singleArgumentExpansion(one)
  TEST(two, "foopy"); // twoArgumentExpansion(two, "foopy")
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In VS2010 this too only returns TEST1 twice

Comment: @YochaiTimmer, this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9338429/390913) suggests a workaround.

Comment: The example in the link works great. Update your answer, or i'll do it later.

Answer (score 1):

First, the page you link explains it is a GCC extension. If you are using visual studio 2010 as your tag implies, I'm not surprised it doesn't work.

Then you aren't using it correctly: you need `##` between the coma and `__VA_ARGS__`. If I do this and fix the typo which makes both TESTx macros print TEST1, I get the behaviour you expect with gcc 4.4

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST1() printf("TEST1\n");
#define TEST2() printf("TEST2\n");

#define CHOOSER(x, y, FUNC,...) FUNC()

#define MANIMACRO(...) CHOOSER(,##__VA_ARGS__,TEST1,TEST2)

int main(void)
{
    MANIMACRO(1);
    MANIMACRO();
}
```

Comment: Again, I'm not surprised that a **GCC extension** is not available with VS2010.