# "Overloading" a Macro With a `#define` Constant

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
//Bad; can't redefine macros; uses later definition.
#define foo          )
#define foo(arg) ,arg)
```

That is, I want `foo` (note: *not* a macro function) to map to one thing, and I want the macro function `foo(arg)` to map to something else.  So `foo` needs to be some `#define` constant (catching both cases) that maps onto . . . something.

---

I haven't been able to figure out a way, (and since this is a macro and a constant, the many [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974170/overloading-a-macro) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683146/can-macros-be-overloaded-by-number-of-arguments) do not apply).  **How can I do this?**

<sup>Evil compiler-/platform-specific options are great too.  Tagging this [c](/questions/tagged/c) for C-macros, although I'm using C++14.</sup>

---

Sidenote (by request): this could be used for e.g. making your own debug overloads for `new` that would work with placement new as well:

```
#define new new(__FILE__,__LINE__ foo
//...
void const* p1 = new       int();
void const* p2 = new (ptr) int();
```

Comment: Can you describe a reason for such a requirement?

Comment: And can you describe the requirement a bit more? I seem to get what you are asking, but don't quite get what you mean to say with the ")" and ",arg)" part of your question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's difficult without rat-holing, but I've added a short example.

Comment: Why do they need the same name? I don't understand what the intent is. Maybe if you described the problem you're trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a preprocessor that has different name spaces for *function*- (with arguments) and *object-like* (plain #defines) macros - I don't know of any that would have that, and it would be fundamentally confusing if there was one, I assume.

I understand you want something like (note this is actually not trying to provide a solution)

```
// NOTE: Example might work in some very trivial use cases
#ifdef DEBUG
#define new(x) new(x);lognew(__FILE__,__LINE__)  
#define pnew(p,x) new (p) (x); lognew(__FILE__,__LINE__)
#else
#define new(x) new(x)
#define pnew(p,x) new(p) (x)
#endif
```

And pnew and new should use the same keyword. No, I don't think that is possible (and I'm glad it isn't ;) ).

Comment: Currently accepting this answer, as it makes a claim that this is impossible. This has been my conclusion as well. If anyone figures out a way to do it, I'll accept that instead.

Answer (score -1):

Functions with variable signatures are only allowed in C++ , called "function overloading".