# Compile time check polymorphic types in C?

Tags: c, type-safety, c11

Polymorphic structs are quite common in C but often involve explicit casts which allow for accidentally casting incompatible structs.

```
struct ID {
    char name[32];
};

struct IntID {
    struct ID id_base;
    int value;
}
struct FloatID {
    struct ID id_base;
    float value;
}

void id_name_set(ID *id, const char *name)
{
    strlcpy(id->name, name, sizeof(id->name));
}

/* macro that happens to use 'id_name_set', this is a bit contrived */
#define ID_NAME_SET_AND_VALUE(id, name, val) \
    do { \
        id_name_set((ID *)id, name); \
        id->value = val; \
    } while(0)

void func(void)
{
    struct { int value; } not_an_id;

    /* this can crash because NotID doesn't have an ID as its first member */
    ID_NAME_SET_AND_VALUE(not_an_id, "name", 10);
}
```

The issue here is we can't type check the `id` argument in the macro against a single type, since it could be an `ID` or any struct with an `ID` as its first member.

A lot of code I've seen simply casts to the struct all over the place, but it seems it is possible to have a more reliable method.

Is there a way to check at compile time?

---

*Note, for the purpose of this question, we can assume all structs use the same member name for the struct they inherit from.*

---

Note, I was hoping to be able to use something like this...

```
#  define CHECK_TYPE_POLYMORPHIC(val, member, struct_name) \
    (void)(_Generic((*(val)), \
        /* base-struct */  struct_name: 0, \
        /* sub-struct */   default: (_Generic(((val)->member), struct_name: 0))))

/* --- snip --- */
/* check that `var` is an `ID`, or `var->id_base` is */
CHECK_TYPE_POLYMORPHIC(var, id_base, ID);
```

...but this fails for `ID` types in the `default` case - because they have no `id` member.

So far the only way I found to do this is to type-check against a complete list of all structs, which isn't ideal in some cases (may be many — or defined locally, therefore not known to the macro, see: [Compile time check against multiple types in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988363/)).

Comment: I can't help but feel this is headed down the wrong track.  If you want C++, use C++.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler. I understand that maybe Im attempting to do something not really supported by C, But I'm not really interested in moving to another language, if its impossible to type-check polymorphic structs, I can make-do with checking against a list of struct's already, but if its possible to add some extra type checks to an existing C codebase, then why not?

Comment: Have you read any documentation from the GObject or gtk+2.0/gtk+3.0 . They achieve this, don't re-invent the wheel. Just ape their code it's copyright is gnu lesser gpl.

Comment: @rhubarbdog - is there a specific keyword/macro to look for relating to this?

Comment: dunno, but the generic type GtkWidget is continually re-cast by say macro GTK_BUTTON, to make this work you have  to compile with correct warnings, -Wall does this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use casts. A cast supposes that you know what you are doing and in the worst case leads to undefined behavior. You'd have to rely on the fact that the types that you are interested in all have that `struct ID` field with the same name.

Then, in the case that you present where you actually have a `do-while` kind of functional macro, you can easily place an auxiliary variable:

```
#define ID_NAME_SET_AND_VALUE(id, name, val) \
    do {                                     \
        ID* _id = &((id)->id_base));         \
        id_name_set(_id, (name));            \
        _id->value = (val);                  \
    } while(0)
```

If all goes well, this is a nop, if not it is a constraint violation and aborts compilation.

In a context where you can't place a variable you could use a compound literal, something like

```
 (ID*){ &((id)->id_base)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing in [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) (the latest C standard) for *compile-time* polymorphism is its 
type-generic expressions using the `_Generic` keyword, but I am not sure it fits your needs.

The [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler also gives you its [`__builtin_type_compatible_p`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) with which you could build e.g. some macros.

You could also customize GCC with some [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extensions