# _Generic: multiple types to a single value?

Tags: c, generics, generic-programming, c11

Using c11 `_Generic` is there a way to map multiple types to a single value?

eg:

```
_Generic(e,      \
    A *:    foo_expression, \
    B **:   foo_expression, \
    C:      foo_expression, \
    enum D: bar_expression, \
    void *: bar_expression)
```

*Is there a way to group types? (this isn't valid syntax just to express the intent)*

```
_Generic(e, \
    A *: B **: C:    foo_expression, \
    enum D: void *:  bar_expression)
```

---

The reason I ask is args `foo` and `baz` can end up being large expressions *(which can't necessarily be refactored into functions)*, so a way to avoid a lot of duplication would be good.

---

Note:

If there is no supported way using `_Generic`, I _could_ make a varargs macro to glue multiple args to a single value...

```
#define GENERIC_TYPE_GLUE3(answer, arg0, arg1) \
    arg0: answer, arg1: answer
#define GENERIC_TYPE_GLUE4(answer, arg0, arg1, arg2) \
    arg0: answer, arg1: answer, arg2: answer
....
```

... have many of these macros, then use a varargs wrapper to automatically use the right one, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24837037/432509

```
_Generic(e,      \
    GENERIC_TYPE_GLUE(foo_expression, short int, long),
    GENERIC_TYPE_GLUE(bar_expression, float, double))
```

(See working example: https://gist.github.com/ideasman42/4426f255880ff6a53080)

Comment: I never actually looked into how generic macros work, but what if you defined new macros for the giant `foo` and `baz` expressions? Does something prevent that from working?

Comment: This will work in most cases, it just means the number of single-use macros may multiply out *(and pollute the name-space)*. I'd rather use the example macro to glue multiple types with a single arg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, similar to `switch` there is no syntax foreseen to regroup multiple cases for `_Generic`. Your regrouping macro approach is probably the correct one for your purpose, then. You may have a look into macro meta programming as is done by boost or my package [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) that allow you to have just one such macro that also does the counting of the cases for.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case you can use the type promotion rules

```
_Generic((e)+0ULL,             \
    unsigned long long:   foo, \
    default:  bar)
```

If you have other cases than floating point, you may even go one step further

```
_Generic((e)+0ULL,             \
    unsigned long long:   foo, \
    default: _Generic((e)+0.0L,\
     long double:   bar,       \
     default:  blur))
```

This supposes that all your expressions `e` have arithmetic type. Remaining for the `default` in would then be `_Complex` types and all pointer types.

For the kind of usage you have in mind you should do such promotions, anyhow, because compilers currently interpret the controlling expression of `_Generic` differently. Some would also consider an object of type `double const` differently from `double`, for example. So this would really give you a lot of cases to consider, if you'd have to differentiate all possible type qualifications.

Comment: The fact type promotion could be used in the example is unrelated to the actual question (not ideal examples then), edited the example.