# Is it possible to prevent duplicate identical arguments to a macro in Rust?

Tags: macros, rust

There are certain rare cases where it may be useful to prevent duplicate arguments to a macro. One example is this [`elem(value, ...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828920) macro to check if `value` is either `A`, `B` or `C`:

```
if (elem(value, A, B, C)) { .... }
```

Someone could accidentally pass in the same argument multiple times, e.g.:

```
if (elem(value, A, B, B)) { .... }
```

While this is valid Rust, it is almost certainly an accident and **highly unlikely** to be what the developer intended. This is a trivial example, actual error cases would be more complicated.

Is there a way to have the compiler warn/error when passing in duplicate arguments?

- Arguments are not necessarily all constants, they could be mixed with variables too.
- This is an actual bug I found in some code. While there's a limit macros/compilers can go to prevent mistakes, this could have been detected early if the macro didn't allow it. These kinds of mistakes should be found in code review but mistakes happen.
- One way to do this (which isn't fool proof), could be to convert the identifiers to strings, then static-assert if any of the identifiers are exact matches. This has the obvious drawback that different identifiers may represent the same constant value. The same identifier could also be written so as to not compare, e.g.: `A[0]` vs `A[ 0 ]`.
- If the preprocessor/compiler can't do this easily, a fall-back solution may be some basic static checking tool.
- I managed to [do this with the C preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31632477/432509).

Comment: If my answer is not what you are looking for, could you please post a comment to explain why?

Answer (score 5):

One way to achieve what you want is the following:

```
macro_rules! unique_args {
    ($($idents:ident),*) => {
        {
            #[allow(dead_code, non_camel_case_types)]
            enum Idents { $($idents,)* __CountIdentsLast }
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! _my_elem {
    ($val:expr, $($var:expr),*) => {{
        $($val == $var)||*
    }};
}

macro_rules! my_elem {
    ($($tt:tt)*) => {{
        unique_args!($($tt)*);
        _my_elem!($($tt)*)
    }};
}
```

The idea is that having the same identifier twice will cause a compiler error because an enum cannot have duplicate variant names.

You can use this as such:

```
if my_elem!(w, x, y, z) {
    println!("{}", w);
}
```

Here is an example with an error:

```
// error[E0428]: a value named `y` has already been defined in this enum
if my_elem!(w, x, y, y) {
    println!("{}", w);
}
```

However, this will only work with identifiers.

If you want to use literals as well, you will need a macro with a different syntax to be able to differentiate between a literal and an identifier:

```
macro_rules! unique_idents {
    () => {
    };
    ($tt:tt) => {
    };
    ($ident1:ident, $ident2:ident) => {
        {
            #[allow(dead_code, non_camel_case_types)]
            enum Idents {
                $ident1,
                $ident2,
            }
        }
    };
    ($ident:ident, lit $expr:expr) => {
    };
    ($ident1:ident, $ident2:ident, $($tt:tt)*) => {
        {
            #[allow(dead_code, non_camel_case_types)]
            enum Idents {
                $ident1,
                $ident2,
            }
            unique_idents!($ident1, $($tt)*);
            unique_idents!($ident2, $($tt)*);
        }
    };
    ($ident:ident, lit $expr:expr, $($tt:tt)*) => {
        unique_idents!($ident, $($tt)*);
    };
    (lit $expr:expr, $($tt:tt)*) => {
        unique_idents!($($tt)*);
    };
}

macro_rules! unique_literals {
    () => {
    };
    ($tt:tt) => {
    };
    (lit $lit1:expr, lit $lit2:expr) => {{
            type ArrayForStaticAssert_ = [i8; 0 - (($lit1 == $lit2) as usize)];
    }};
    (lit $lit:expr, $ident:ident) => {
    };
    (lit $lit1:expr, lit $lit2:ident, $($tt:tt)*) => {{
            unique_literals!(lit $lit1, lit $lit2);
            unique_literals!(lit $lit1, $($tt)*);
            unique_literals!(lit $lit2, $($tt)*);
    }};
    (lit $lit:expr, $ident:ident, $($tt:tt)*) => {
        unique_literals!(lit $lit, $($tt)*);
    };
    ($ident:ident, $($tt:tt)*) => {
        unique_literals!($($tt)*);
    };
}

macro_rules! unique_args2 {
    ($($tt:tt)*) => {{
        unique_idents!($($tt)*);
        unique_literals!($($tt)*);
    }};
}

macro_rules! _elem {
    () => {
        false
    };
    ($val:expr) => {
        false
    };
    ($val1:expr, $val2:expr) => {{
        $val1 == $val2
    }};
    ($val1:expr, lit $val2:expr) => {{
        $val1 == $val2
    }};
    ($val1:expr, $val2:expr, $($tt:tt)*) => {{
        $val1 == $val2 || _elem!($val1, $($tt)*)
    }};
    ($val1:expr, lit $val2:expr, $($tt:tt)*) => {{
        $val1 == $val2 || _elem!($val1, $($tt)*)
    }};
}

macro_rules! elem {
    ($($tt:tt)*) => {{
        unique_args2!($($tt)*);
        _elem!($($tt)*)
    }};
}
```

The `uniq_idents!` macro uses the same trick as above.

The `unique_literals!` macro will cause a `subtract with overflow` error that is caught at compile time.

With these macros, you will need to prefix each literal by `lit`:

```
if elem!(w, x, lit 1, z) {
    println!("{}", w);
}
```

Here are some examples of errors:

```
// error[E0428]: a value named `y` has already been defined in this enum
if elem!(w, x, y, y) {
    println!("{}", w);
}

// error[E0080]: constant evaluation error
if elem!(w, x, lit 1, z, lit 1) {
    println!("{}", w);
}
```

I think it is the best we can do without using a compiler plugin.

It is possible to improve these macros, but you get the idea.

Even though there is a [`stringify!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.stringify!.html) macro that can be use to convert any expression to a string, I don't think we currently have a way to compare these strings at compile time (without a compiler plugin), at least until we have `const fn`.

Comment: Nice answer, in practice often some of the identifiers will be something like `a::b.c` which limits some practical use. I managed to make a macro that detects this in C using *(quite evil preprocessor strcmp - https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/blender/blob/7ea280cc6a5cb499c90b843651df14f97db29bcb/source/blender/blenlib/BLI_utildefines.h#L514)*

Comment: You can also create a procedural macro by writing a [compiler plugin](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/compiler-plugins.html) where you will have greater control and be able to achieve your goal.