# How to write a macro in Rust to match any element in a set?

Tags: macros, rust, variadic-macros

In C, I'm used to having:

```
if (ELEM(value, a, b, c)) { ... }
```

which is a macro with a variable number of arguments to avoid typing out

```
if (value == a || value == b || value == c) { ... }
```

A C example can be seen in [Varargs `ELEM` macro for use with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836793/varargs-elem-macro-for-use-with-c).

Is this possible in Rust? I assume it would use `match`. If so, how would variadic arguments be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

```rust
macro_rules! cmp {
    // Hack for Rust v1.11 and prior.
    (@as_expr $e:expr) => { $e };

    ($lhs:expr, $cmp:tt any $($rhss:expr),*) => {
        // We do this to bind `$lhs` to a name so we don't evaluate it multiple
        // times.  Use a leading underscore to avoid an unused variable warning
        // in the degenerate case of no `rhs`s.
        match $lhs { _lhs => {
            false || $(
                cmp!(@as_expr _lhs $cmp $rhss)
            ) || *
        //    ^- this is used as a *separator* between terms
        }}
    };

    // Same, but for "all".
    ($lhs:expr, $cmp:tt all $($rhss:expr),*) => {
        match $lhs { _lhs => {
            true && $( cmp!(@as_expr _lhs $cmp $rhss) ) && *
        }}
    };
}

fn main() {
    let value = 2;
    if cmp!(value, == any 1, 2, 3) {
        println!("true! value: {:?}", value);
    }
    if cmp!(value*2, != all 5, 7, 1<<7 - 1) {
        println!("true! value: {:?}", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Rust v1.11 and prior* — does that mean that ugly wart has finally been fixed?

Comment: @Shepmaster *Apparently.*  Haven't had an opportunity to test it thoroughly, myself, but looks like the reparse trick might be on the way out.

Answer (score 2):

First off, if your `a`, `b`, and `c` are concrete values, you can just use `match`:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 42;

    match x {
        1 | 2 | 3 => println!("foo"),
        42 => println!("bar"),
        _ => println!("nope"),
    }
}
```

If you want to match on variables you need to write the `match` arms like this:

```
match x {
    x if x == a || x == b || x == c => println!("foo"),
    42 => println!("bar"),
    _ => println!("nope"),
}
```

…which is basically what you want to avoid.

But: A pretty direct translation of your C macro is also possible!

```
macro_rules! elem {
    ($val:expr, $($var:expr),*) => {
        $($val == $var)||*
    }
}

fn main() {
    let y = 42;
    let x = 42;

    if elem!(x, 1, 3, y) {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm partial to writing this without a macro, taking advantage of `contains` on arrays.

```
fn main() {
    if [1, 2, 3, 4].contains(&4) {
        println!("OK");
    }
}
```

It's hard to predict what will happen to this when optimized, but if absolute performance is a goal you'd do well to benchmark each approach.

Comment: Not as good as benchmarking your actual code, but here is a paper (from 2007) on how LLVM optimizes/lowers switch statements: http://llvm.org/pubs/2007-05-31-Switch-Lowering.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, the following macro expands to do each check.

```
macro_rules! elem {
    ($n:expr, $( $hs:expr ),*) => ($( $n == $hs )||* );
}

fn main() {
    if elem!(4, 1, 2, 3, 4) {
        println!("OK");
    }
}
```

---

Thanks to @vfs on #rust in IRC.