# Visual C++ preprocessor: __VA_ARGS__ in variadic macro invocation treated as a single token

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

In GCC, I have been successfully using the following `IS_1` macro for some time. It expands to the value of transmitted macro when the transmitted token is defined, 0 when it is undefined (or explicitly defined to be 0):

```
// Concatenate two tokens without performing macro expansion.
#define CONCAT(A, B) A##B

// Possibly expand macros in transmitted tokens and concatenate the results.
#define EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT(A, B) CONCAT(A,B)

#define _0_1 0,1
#define IS_X_1_SUB(X,Y,...) Y

// Problem with MSC occurs here: __VA_ARGS__ all end up in sub-macro's first parameter
#define IS_X_1(...) IS_X_1_SUB(__VA_ARGS__, 0)

// This is the useful macro: expands to X's value when defined, 0 otherwise.
#define IS_1(X) IS_X_1(EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT(_0_,X))
```

**Example use case:**

```
#define THIS_IS_TRUE 1
IS_1( THIS_IS_TRUE )
// Expected expansion: 1

IS_1( THIS_IS_FALSE )
// Expected expansion: 0

#define ZERO 0
IS_1( ZERO )
// Expected expansion: 0
```

Now, I'm hitting a problem trying to use this macro with Visual C++'s compiler, where `__VA_ARGS__` in the `IS_X_1` macro expansion is apparently transmitted as a single parameter to the `IS_X_1_SUB` macro, which in turn always expands to 0.

This is visible in the following dumbed-down example:

```
#define FOO(X, ...) X foo __VA_ARGS___
#define BAR(...) FOO(__VA_ARGS__, bar)
BAR(42, 42)
// expected (and actual result with GCC): 42 foo 42 bar
// output of MSC preprocessor: 42, 42 foo bar
```

- Is this a bug?
- Was it not supposed to work as it did with GCC in the first place?
- Is there a workaround or an otherwise more portable solution?

Comment: Sorry, but that looks awful. If you ever have to maintain such code, you for sure will know why.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this behavior is unspecified.

Comment: @Olaf Care to elaborate on that judgement? I'm all ears if you have actual suggestions as to how I could improve my coding style. Regards.

Comment: Also note that you're comparing a C++ compiler with a C compiler.

Comment: As I don't know your full application, just a general advice after having fixed too much of (unintentionally) obfuscated code: Don't get too fancy with macros!

Comment: Try Boost preprocessor:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/variadic_macros.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183993/msvc-variadic-macro-expansion