# Possible to pass comma and args into C++ macro?

Tags: c++

Wondering if it's possible to assign a C++ macro two values separated by a comma and use this macro to later define two parameters passed to a macro?

E.g., for the macro

```
#define ADD_TWO(first, second) first + second
```

This works:

```
    int foo = ADD_TWO(0, 42);
```

But this doesn't

```
#define ZERO_COMMA_FORTY_TWO 0,42
int bar = ADD_TWO(ZERO_COMMA_FORTY_TWO);
```

Is there a way to define a macro as two or more parameters to another macro?

EDIT: Environment is VS2017

Comment: Avoid macro programming.

Comment: @Ron you'll take macro metaprogramming from my cold, dead hands!

Comment: @Quentin Lol, I'll upvote your comment instead.

Comment: Macros are fun:  `ADD_TWO(3.14159, true)` and `ADD_TWO("Macro", 3.14159)`.  Use function (or inline functions) instead.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I highly doubt his actual use case is adding two values - probably just a fun MCVE

Comment: The Boost.PP library has a *lot* of useful tools for this kind of thing.

Comment: @hit is correct--no sane person would use a macro when a function would do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this directly. A macro with two arguments expects two arguments to be passed, and `ZERO_COMMA_FORTY_TWO` is seen as one argument. However, you can add an additional layer of indirection to expand the macros that are passed in via variadic macros:

```
#define ADD_TWO_IMPL(first, second) first + second
#define ADD_TWO(...) ADD_TWO_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ZERO_COMMA_FORTY_TWO 0, 42
```

Then, both of these work

```
int foo = ADD_TWO(0, 42);
int bar = ADD_TWO(ZERO_COMMA_FORTY_TWO);
```

---

Apparently, MSVC has [a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183993/msvc-variadic-macro-expansion) that causes it to reject this code, but we can work around that (with more indirection):

```
#define ADD_TWO_IMPL(first, second) first + second
#define UNPACK(macro, args) macro args
#define ADD_TWO(...) UNPACK(ADD_TWO_IMPL, (__VA_ARGS__))
```

This version compiles on [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/g/mrwcV9), [GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/K5w5Xr), and [Clang](https://godbolt.org/g/RHwgst)

Comment: @buttonsrtoys Adapted the workaround to work for your specific use case