# c++: ensure enum values are unique at compile time

Tags: c++, enums, unique

I have the following `enum` that describes error codes:

```
 typedef enum {
    et_general           = 0,
    et_INVALID_CLI_FLAG  = 1,
    ...
    et_undef = 500
  } EErrorType;
```

The main reason why I explicitly write the enum values, is to ease the debug process.
Anyways, I wonder if there's a way, to **make the compiler complain about non unique values**. 
I can always check it at run time easily, but I'd like to avoid that.

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11263396/1798187) and reviewed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11263967/1798187). As I understand, that answer suggests to generate the enum in such way that it "*make it much harder to make mistakes*".
I'd would like to leave the enum definition as is, or close to it.

Comment: How about N^2 `static_assert`s?

Comment: If you want to ease debugging you might want to add a to_string function to your `enum` instead of specifying the values manually.

Comment: Create a build step script that parses the enum and checks it for duplicate values?

Comment: Sorry, don't you can do that in compile time with an enum.

Comment: use template function to check. variadic arguments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C/C++ enums: Detect when multiple items map to same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576868/c-c-enums-detect-when-multiple-items-map-to-same-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if Boost is available in your scenario, so here is a solution where the `enum` has to be defined in a pre-processor sequence. That sequence is then used to build the enum and a corresponding `mpl::vector` and we compute if the elements of the `vector` are unique in an odd-fashion. We might want to define a proper `is_unique` algorithm first, but this should do.

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/sort.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/unique.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/size.hpp>

#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/enum.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/transform.hpp>


#define MYENUM ((FOO, 0))((BAR, 1))((BAZ, 2))

#define GET_NAME(_, __, elem) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, elem) = BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, elem)
#define GET_VALUE(_, __, elem) boost::mpl::int_<BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, elem)>

enum E {
  BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM(GET_NAME, _, MYENUM))
};

typedef boost::mpl::sort< 
  boost::mpl::vector<
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM(GET_VALUE, _, MYENUM))
    > 
  >::type evalues;

typedef boost::mpl::unique< evalues, boost::is_same<boost::mpl::_1, boost::mpl::_2> >::type uniqued;
static_assert(boost::mpl::size<uniqued>::value == boost::mpl::size<evalues>::value, "enum values not unique");

int main()
{

  return 0;
}
```

If you change the enum definition to:

```
#define MYENUM ((FOO, 0))((BAR, 1))((BAZ, 2))((BAZZ, 2))
```

you will get an error stating the `static_assert failed "enum values not unique"`.

Answer (score 5):

One can write a dummy `switch` statement with the enum values as labels – *that* will guarantee their uniqueness. Placed in a dummy unreferenced function, it won't get into the executable.

Comment: This is at one and the same time a nauseating kludge and an elegant hack. Moreover, for class enums decent compilers will warn you if you forget to add a new enum value to the dummy (don't use a `default` label).

Answer (score 3):

This solution does modify the enum definition, so if you can put up with that...

This also assumes that the values are mainly sequential.

**Don't specify the values.
After the enum definition, have static_assert checks for humans to know the values.**

```
enum EErrorType : uint16_t
{
  et_general = 0,
  et_INVALID_CLI_FLAG,
  et_FOO,
  et_BAR,
  ...
  et_undef = 500
};
static_assert(EErrorType::et_general          == 0, "Wrong enum value");
static_assert(EErrorType::et_INVALID_CLI_FLAG == 1, "Wrong enum value");
static_assert(EErrorType::et_FOO              == 2, "Wrong enum value");
static_assert(EErrorType::et_BAR              == 3, "Wrong enum value");
...
static_assert(EErrorType::et_undef            == 500, "Wrong enum value");
```

Thus, they are mostly automatically assigned and therefore unique, and you can also have human-readable values are for debugging and other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The best to make sure the values are all unique, is simply to not explicitly define them.  For your debug, simply write a helper program that gives you the values, something like:

```
awk 'NR>1{print $1, i; i +=1} eerror.h
```

this assumes the first line of `eerror.h` is:

```
typedef enum {
```

Comment: I understand, but as I wrote, I'd like to keep it for debug proposes.

Comment: @idanshmu ok, added that to answer

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't provide any features to restrict the enumerations in this way.

You can do it at run-time with a little hackery if you're prepared to use a macro to create your `enum` (see below), and you may be able to use something like gccxml, doxygen or some other parser to verify a list of enumerations at some point in your build process.

Simpler but very feeble, if you adopted a coding standard of an enumeration per line you could relate differences in `__LINE__` numbers to enumerations, but that wouldn't catch e.g. a duplicate followed by a gap.

Example of run-time indexing of enumerations using a macro (not intended to be particularly robust - e.g. if enumeration values could have embedded commas, comments etc. you'd need to create a stack of matching `<[{(` and quotes etc..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

namespace Benum
{
    struct Meta
    {
        Meta(const char* p, int* p_values)
        {
            while (*p)
            {
                if (isalnum(*p) || *p == '_')
                {
                    const char* p_from = p;
                    while (isalnum(*p) || *p == '_')
                        ++p;
                    std::string idn = std::string(p_from, p - p_from);
                    int_to_string_[*p_values] = idn;
                    string_to_int_[idn] = *p_values;
                    ++p_values;
                }
                else if (*p == '=')
                    while (*p && *p != ',')
                        ++p;
                else
                    ++p;
            }
        }
        std::ostream& out(std::ostream& os, int i) const
        {
            Int_To_String::const_iterator it = int_to_string_.find(i);
            if (it != int_to_string_.end())
                return os << it->second;
            else
                return os << "<unmatched enum " << i << '>';
        }
        typedef std::map<int, std::string> Int_To_String;
        std::map<int, std::string> int_to_string_;
        std::map<std::string, int> string_to_int_;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct Incrementing
    {
        Incrementing(int n) : n_(n) { s_next_implicit_ = n + 1; }
        Incrementing() : n_(s_next_implicit_++) { }
        operator int() const { return n_; }
        int n_;
        static int s_next_implicit_;
    };

    template <typename T>
    int Incrementing<T>::s_next_implicit_;
}

#define BENUM(IDN, ...) \
    enum IDN ## _Enum { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    struct IDN { \
        typedef IDN ## _Enum Enum; \
        IDN(Enum e) : e_(e) { } \
        IDN& operator=(Enum e) { e_ = e; return *this; } \
        operator Enum() const { return e_; } \
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Enum e) { \
            return IDN::meta().out(os, e); \
        } \
        static const Benum::Meta& meta() { \
            static Benum::Incrementing<IDN> __VA_ARGS__; \
            static int values[] = { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
            static Benum::Meta m(#__VA_ARGS__, values); \
            return m; \
        } \
        Enum e_; \
    };

// benum example usage...

BENUM(My_Enum, One = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3, Four = 4, Whats_Next);

int main()
{
    std::cout << One << ' ' << Two << ' ' << Three << ' ' <<
        Whats_Next << '\n';
    const Benum::Meta& meta = My_Enum::meta();
    for (std::map<int, std::string>::const_iterator i = meta.int_to_string_.begin();
        i != meta.int_to_string_.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << i->first << ' ' << i->second << '\n';
}
```