# C++11 Enum class containing duplicate values

Tags: c++, c++11

The classic C++ enums don't have a straight forward method to detect duplicate values.

Is this issue addressed in the new C++11 `enum class`?

```
enum class ConnectionState : uint32_t
{
    Connecting,
    Reconnecting = 2,
    Disconnecting,
    LocalConnection,
    NoNetwork = 2,
    WifiNetwork,
    Last
}
```

Comment: This is not an issue, it's intentional, and useful.

Comment: @JonathanWakely There is an issue here: sometimes, you do want a way to prevent/detect duplicates.  Other times you don't.  The lack of a way to easily detect it is an issue; the lack of it preventing duplicates is not an issue, and not asked for in the question.  This issue should be solved if/when the reflection working group gets their work into a standard...

Comment: duplicates: [C/C++ enums: Detect when multiple items map to same value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2576868/995714), [c++: ensure enum values are unique at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21378938/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C/C++ enums: Detect when multiple items map to same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576868/c-c-enums-detect-when-multiple-items-map-to-same-value)

Comment: the solution is to use the Boost Preprocessor library, or write a switch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no way to detect or prevent multiple identical enum values in an enum.

[The reflection working group](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3814.html) is working on how to add reflection -- the ability for C++ code to introspect C++ code -- to the language.  In the long list of stuff that reflection covers, there is a short list being worked on, and in that short list, examining the values of an enumeration at compile time is there.

[N4428](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4428.pdf) contains a proposal for enum reflection.  [There are some partial implementations](http://aantron.github.io/better-enums/demo/C++17ReflectionProposal.html) out there.

Under N4428, detecting duplicates would be easy.  You can get the number of enumeration values, and their value, all at compile time.  Simply create a pack of all the enum values in order, and test that they are unique.  Then toss the result of that test into a `static_assert`.

The end result could be:

```
template<class E>
constexpr bool all_values_unique(); // todo

static_assert( all_values_unique<ConnectionState>(), "Duplicate enum value detected" );
```

Prior to something like that reflection proposal being added to C++, this is not possible.

You can fake it using macros -- have a macro that both creates your enum and creates reflection traits information about it -- then write `all_values_unique` that uses the reflection traits information.  This has the advantage that if/when the standard and/or your compiler gets the reflection features needed, it may be easy to strip out your macros.