# C how to convert large list of defines to strings for comparison to user input string

Tags: c

I read an interesting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650663/possible-to-convert-list-of-defines-into-strings-c) on how to convert a list of error code defines from the error code to the error string using a giant switch statement.   I have a slightly different question though.

Given a large text file of thousands of register defines ie:

```
#define setup_register 0x01
```

I'd like to be able to take input from the command line like `write setup_register 0xFF`.  Then in my code I'd lookup what setup_register's address was (0x01) and write to it.

Is there a C way to get at the setup_register address?  I suppose I could parse the file and create a new one, or do it manually, but that means it has to be done each time it changes.

Comment: You say "a large *text* file", but the example content has the form of a C macro definition.  Is the file in question in fact a C source file (maybe a header file) that is available during compilation of your program, or is it really used as a plain text file (meaning the program reads it at run time)?

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion, it is a very large C source file.  A long list of #define statements in the form above.

Answer (score 1):

The `setup_register` is a C preprocessor symbol.  Such symbols can be stringified if it is a [macro argument](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html).  Otherwise as far I as know it cannot be done.

I would write a script in your favorite scripting language (Ruby, Python, Perl) that looks for lines of the form "#define [A-Za-Z_]+ 0x[0-9a-fA-f]+", and then parses out the name and generates an array of structures that has the string and corresponding value.  Hash the string, put the structure in a hash table, and you are good to go.

Comment: In fact, the preprocessor has an operator (`#`) for converting preprocessor symbols to C strings, so `setup_register` et. al. *can* be available to the code as a string.  That doesn't necessarily mean it would be a bad idea to process all those definitions as you describe, but please try to avoid asserting falsehoods.

Comment: And indeed, one mechanism or another for building a hash table with the strings as keys is certainly the way I would go.