# C++ enumeration

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

my question is about enumeration,my codes are :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    enum bolumler {programcilik,donanim,muhasebe,motor,buro} bolum;
    bolum = donanim;
    cout << bolum << endl;
    bolum += 2;  // bolum=motor
    cout << bolum;

    return 0;
}
```

The output should be
1
3
but according to these codes the error is:

```
 error C2676: binary '+=' : 'enum main::bolumler' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
Error executing cl.exe.

111.obj - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Can you help me ?The other question is what can I do if I want to see the output like that "muhasebe"?

Comment: use the source code button in the editor, otherwise it's hard to read.

Comment: In fact, all the reason it fails is because `E1 += E2` is `E1 = E1 + E2`, even for enumerations. But the `+` built-in operator doesn't yield the enum type back, so this use of `+=` fails.

Comment: There are a number of options for solving the last question you have:  there are a number of answers in reply to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571816/is-it-possible-to-define-enumalpha

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `+=` on variables of an `enum` type unless you define `operator+=`.

If you really needed to you could add 2 and then cast back to the enum type, but this is not very nice code.

```
bolum = (bolumler)(bolum + 2); /* bolum=motor */
```

About your other question:

> 111.obj - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) Can you help me ?The other question is what can I do if I want to see the output like that "muhasebe"?

You would need to manually convert the enum variable to a string with a switch statement.

```
std::string enum_to_string(bolumler val)
{
    swtich(val)
    {
       case programcilik:
         return "programcilik";
      //....
```

Comment: Not without writing the `operator+=` definition to do it.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, you can't do this kind of arithmetic on a enum type. If you need it, write your own += operator, like this:

```
bolumler& operator+=(bolumler& v1, int v2) {
    return v1 = bolumler(int(v1) + v2);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't properly overflow, that is, `buro+=1` isn't `programcilik`. Also, if I can say `a+=b`, I expect `a+b` to work as well, so `bolumler operator+(bolumler,bolumler)` should be overloaded, too. (And then there's `a-b` and `a-=b`.) Still, overloading the operator was the first non-hackish solution to the problem, so +1 from me nevertheless.

Comment: @sbi yes, the value won't _wrap_ automatically. The best one can do is to write a macro or a templated class to declare all operators for a given type. Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0):

An enum is not of type int, although the values are substituted by numeric vals. Thus, you cannot use operators on it. Use integers instead of an enum to make it work.

For string output, you have to use strings. A descriptor's name cannot be displayed as string. Descriptors are often stripped completely when compiling your code anyway, so you can't even find them after disassembling the program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that enums can implicitly convert to `int`, but `int` can't implicitly convert to enum types.

When you add 2 to an enum, the result is an `int` or `unsigned int` (or possibly some other integer type, if the enum contains really big values), which isn't allowed to be assigned back to an enum without a cast. To preserve this restriction, there's also no `+=` operator on enums.

You could declare `bolum` as an int, instead of being of enum type, or you could write something like:

```
bolum = static_cast<bolumler>(bolum+2);
```

But beware that this is a bit risky. `bolum+2` is still in the valid range of the enumerated type `bolumler`, and actually so is `buro+2` for technical reasons to do with the exact way that the range of an enum is defined. But in general you can't just go adding 2 to an enum value and expect it necessarily to still be in range of the enum. The sole purpose of using an enumerated type instead of an int is to get extra type safety: if you don't want that, then just define a bunch of integer constants for the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that what you are trying to achieve does not make sense in the context of an enum.

You could substitute any value instead of `2`, but what happens if the value you get back does not correspond to any value of the enum ? It's undefined...

I've run into the problem a couple of times, notably it seems perfectly reasonable to iterate over the values of an enum... The only solution I found was to stash the values into a container (`vector` for example) and then iterate over the container instead.