# C++ equivalent of Java Enum.valueOf()

Tags: c++, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to define enumalpha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571816/is-it-possible-to-define-enumalpha)

Is there any equivalent of Java Enum.valueOf(string) on C++?

Comment: Not for the general case, but there are ways to make this "easier" using the preprocessor:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571816/is-it-possible-to-define-enumalpha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no table of names generated by the compiler (unless you count debug information), but if you create one (or use e.g. [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/output.html) which parses the source code and [can output such lists in XML format](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html)) then you can use a dictionary of some type, such as `std::map<string, int>` to turn an identifier into its numeric value.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't even the much simpler task of going the other way (enum to string), you'd need to write it yourself